# Slight misalignment of table notes when using TableNotes in combination with longtable with tiny font size

Tags: longtable, tablenotes, threeparttablex

I have a tiny problem. I have the following longtable often over various pages (the one here is just a MWE) and I am using threeparttablex to add notes. All fine with the tiny size notes placement and alignment. However, I also want to have the entries in the table with tiny size, and if I do that, then the notes get slightly misaligned. Any solutions to the tiny problem are very welcome!

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{arydshln}


\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
\tiny
\item [$\filledtriangledown$] Note 1
\item [$\circ$] Note 2
\end{TableNotes}

%\tiny % If I add \tiny here Note 1 and Note 2 get slightly misaligned
\begin{longtable}{cccc}
\caption{Observations}\label{tab:X}\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
type & type & unit & source\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
unit & unit & unit & unit\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{r}%
{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

Asian & Yellow & X & R\\
American & Red & Y & R\\
& & &\\
\cdashline{1-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\textbf{Mean type}} & Z &\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{(standard deviation)} & (SD) &\\

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Please, note that I am aware of the booktabs package, but I need a dashed cmidrule, and to my knowledge that package does not provide this solution.

Comment: I tried putting \insertTableNotes inside a tabular, and they looked exactly the same (relative to an \hline).

Comment: OK. Thanks John, but I guess tabular is less than ideal for tables spanning multiple pages, plus that would force me to rewrite code for dozens of tables.............. my solution prior to TableNotes was to use a shortstack and textsuperscrits, but the alignment of the resulting notes is also not perfect. TableNotes would be the best solution, but always in combination with longtable, which brings us back to the original question..............

Comment: What I meant was, the problem has nothing to do with longtable.  Where exactly do you want the notes to show up?

Comment: I want them to show up as in the MWE, right below the last longtable horizontal line. As I said, if I use tiny fontsize for both tablenotes and longtable, the notes get slightly misaligned..............

Comment: First, make sure you run it several times so that longtable can equalize its margins.  If you mean the small indentation, that appears to be built into tablenotes.

Comment: I think I understood your point. If the alignment of table notes is preserved with tabular regardless of fontsize, then the same should happen with longtable, which I guess is just a more elaborated construction than tabular.............. it actually worked fine, I mean the alignment of notes was preserved, when I used \begin{TableNotes} and \end{TableNotes} instead of insertTableNotes, but when I tried to insert the remaining code with the actual longtable values, dahshed cmidrule, and so forth and so on, I got some kind of compilation error..............

Comment: Yes, I mean the small indentation. If you look closely, this indentation is exactly the same for Notes 1 and 2 for a longtable with \normalsize, but slightly different for the same longtable with \tiny. Anyway, if there is a solution it seems to be complicated..............

Comment: Use the [flushleft] options for tablenotes and tablenotesx.