# siunitx: horizontal alignment of rows with integers, non-integers with variable number of decimals, "surrounding material", and brackets

Tags: siunitx, brackets, alignment, decimal-number

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{longtable}{cS[input-symbols=()]c}
\caption{MWE}\label{tab:B.1}\\
\hline
Description & $X$ & REF\\
& $\mathrm{\left[\%\right]}$ &\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
%\caption* {Table 1: \textit{continued from previous page}}\\
\hline
Description & $X$ & REF\\
& $\mathrm{\left[\%\right]}$ &\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{r}%
{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\shortstack[l]{\textsuperscript{a}Note type 1\\
\textsuperscript{$\smallsquare$}Note type 2, entry 1\\
\textsuperscript{$\circ$}Note type 2, entry 2}}
\endlastfoot

& 70.55\textsuperscript{a}&\\
& {92.5}\textsuperscript{a,$\smallsquare$}&\\
& {75}\textsuperscript{a,$\smallsquare$}&\\
& {0}\textsuperscript{a,$\circ$}&\\

\cdashline{1-2}
Mean                        & 53.26 &\\
(standard deviation)        & (39.52) &\\
(sample size)               & (4) &\\

\end{longtable}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

... and I would like siunitx to automatically recognize the "surrounding material" in rows 1-to-4 of column 2 in accordance with the changing number of decimals; as well as to appropriately deal with the brackets in the last row of the same column. As you see, I tried (following the package description) to protect the numbers in rows 2-to-4 with {}, but then the alignment with respect to the initially centered decimal marker (row 1) gets lost. Could anyone please help?

After discussion, this is the latest version of the MWE:

```
\sisetup{table-format=2.2,group-digits=false,input-symbols={()},table-space- 
text-pre=(,table-space-text-post=),table-align-text-post=false}

\begin{longtable}{cSc}
\caption{MWE}\label{tab:B.1}\\
\hline
Description & $X$ & REF\\
& $\mathrm{\left[\%\right]}$ &\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
%\caption* {Table 1: \textit{continued from previous page}}\\
\hline
Description & $X$ & REF\\
& $\mathrm{\left[\%\right]}$ &\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{r}%
{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\shortstack[l]{\textsuperscript{a}Note type 1\\
\textsuperscript{$\smallsquare$}Note type 2, entry 1\\
\textsuperscript{$\circ$}Note type 2, entry 2}}
\endlastfoot

& 70.55\textsuperscript{a}&\\
& 92.5\textsuperscript{a,$\smallsquare$}&\\
& (75)\textsuperscript{a,$\smallsquare$}&\\
& 0\textsuperscript{a,$\circ$}&\\

\cdashline{1-2}
Mean                        & 53.26 &\\
(standard deviation)        & (39.52) &\\
(sample size)               & (4) &\\
```

I just need to switch the entries in between brackets one position to the right. Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: thanks a lot Zarko! I removed the protectors {} and the S parameter in longtable, and added your sisetup parameters. All is as desired, except the brackets in the last row, which are still misaligned. Could you elaborate on the meaning of your sisetup parameters? I am familiar with table-format=2.2 and input-symbols ={()}, but not with the other parameters. I guess table-space-text-pre=(, is to adjust the left bracket and table-space-text-post={)a} the right bracket, but I don't understand the ={)a}. Shouldn't it be just =)? The final parameter must have to do with the "post-text" superscripts

Comment: actually, I got a better result by using only `\sisetup{table-format=2.2, input-symbols={()}, table-align-text-post=false}`, again with the exception of the last row, which is still misaligned

Comment: I updated the MWE above with a second table preceded by `\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-digits=false, input-symbols={()}, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=), table-align-text-post=false}` and with 75 (row 3) with brackets as well, which is my latest version. I almost get the perfect alignment. I would just need to somehow switch the entries in row 3 (75) and in the last row (4) one position to the right..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX is mark-up language, meaning that you need to provide instruction, how the resulting document should looks. Expectation, that the LaTeX or `siunitx` package will itself figure out how the column specification should be is therefore unrealistic.

In your case, you should define a way, how you like to have formatted numbers. For example, I would (re)design your table on the following way:

[image]

As you can see, thin the table are used `\tnote` from the package `threeparttablex`. It enable shorter and consistent way to insert notes in table. The first and last column I would left align, but this you can change as you wish. In the second column I would use `S` column with setting as shown in MWE below.

In the case, that you like to have longer column header with two or more line of content, than use of the `\thead` command from the package `makecell` can be handy. For example:

```
% preamble
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadnote{\bfseries\small}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
% column header for the second column
{\thead{two line\\ long text}}
```

Its use in MWE below is not shown since for column headers, as you have showed in question, `\thead{...}` is not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable, multirow, threeparttablex} % <---
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format=2.2,              % 2 integers, 2 decimals
         input-symbols={( )},           % allowed symbols
         table-space-text-pre=(,        % reserved space for (
         table-space-text-post={)a},    % reserved space for ) + one symbol(\circ) 
         table-align-text-post=false    % notes are aligned at numbers
         }  
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}\small
\item[a]                Note type 1
\item[$\smallsquare$]   Note type 2, entry 1
\item[$\circ$]          Note type 2, entry 2 
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{  l
                    S
                    l}
\caption{MWE}\label{tab:B.1}\\
    \hline
Description & $X\ [\si{\%}]$ & REF\\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{MWE \textit{continued from previous page}}\\
     \hline   
Description & $X\ \si{\%}]$ & REF\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
    \hline
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

    & 70.55\tnote{a}                &   \cite{???}   \\
    & 92.5\tnote{a,$\smallsquare$}  &   \cite{??}    \\
    & 75\tnote{a,$\smallsquare$}    &   \\
    & 0\tnote{a,$\circ$}            &   \\
\cdashline{1-2}
Mean                        & 53.26 &\\
(standard deviation)        & 39.52 &\\
(sample size)               & {(4)} &\\
\end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, but I have tried the ThreePartTable before and if I remember well, I had problems with the final font size I must use which is \tiny. As for the units next to the variable in the header, I would do that, but I have large tables, and I really cannot use landscape mode either, hence the option for the units in the next row. As for the alignment question it seems difficult with siunitx..............

Comment: `threeparttable` per se, not change used font size. If you not give adequate information about your table, how can someone know, what you like to have?

Comment: thanks again Zarko. I will have a look at the code you proposed. This was my own MWE with the problematic combination of `\tiny`, `TableNotes`, and `ThreePartTable`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527249/slight-misalignment-of-table-notes-when-using-tablenotes-in-combination-with-lon

Comment: yes. I made a quick test of your code with `\tiny` fontsize and the problem persists, namely the slight misalignment of the notes' descriptions under the table. So, I will for sure be using `\textsuperscript` for now. As for the siunitx alignment issues, I might just skip brackets in general. Need to think..............

Comment: @Euclides no, i can't confirm this issue. Nor at this table or in  your previous question. BTW, why you should use `tiny` font size?. The smallest font for readable tables is `\footnotesize`. Don't expect that readers will use magnifying glass for reading your table :-). I suggest you to edit your question to show the table row with the largest amount of (dummy) text. With it we will have better insight in your problem.

Comment: the tables need to be submitted to a journal with **_very_** strict guidelines concerning margins, so I really don't have an alternative in terms of font size. We'll see how the journal deals with that specific question, later. As for the alignment of `tablenotes` below a `longtable` with `tiny` font size, you don't confirm, but the colleague that dealt with that separate question confirmed it. Anyway, I'm not using `threeparttable`. The only real issue left is whether to use brackets around numbers in siunitx columns and corresponding tradeoffs, or not..............

Comment: I voted for your answer Zarko. It addressed the question of horizontal alignment of integers or nonintegers of variable precision surrounded by nonnumerical material, with respect to a centered decimal marker, and in a seemingly general way; **_except_** when the material surrounding an integer (or a noninteger with precision = maximum precision of noninteger in sinunitx-governed column minus one), consists of or contains brackets, but I probably can live without brackets, for now. Thanks a lot again and best regards!