# How does one keep a constant indentation for multiline items in tablenotes of a threeparttable?

Tags: indentation, threeparttable, patching, tablenotes

Here an illustrative MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tnote{a} \\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tnote{b} \\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tnote{c} \\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tnote{d} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
    \item[a]Test for number 2.
    \item[b]Test for number 6.
    \item[c]Test for number 10.
    \item[d]Test for number 14.
    \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It can probably be achieved, if something similar to this is added to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\TPTdoTablenotes{%
  \TPTnoteSettings
}{%
  \TPTnoteSettings
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}% % VERTICAL SPACING BETWEEN ITEMS
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\TPTdoTablenotes failed}}
\makeatother
```

... but I'm not sure about how to use those options, yet.

Comment: How or where is `\captionabove` defined?

Comment: **@Mico**: I removed the `\captionabove` piece of code, as it was not relevant for the question I raised, and also changed the document class and simplified the choice of parameters therein..............

Comment: If you WANT hanging indentation, don't use [flushleft].  You can also use `\begin{tablenotes}[normal]`.

Comment: **@Kormylo**: thanks John! I'll keep that in mind..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert items of `tablenotes` in `parbox` (first possibilities):

```
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\scriptsize
    \item[a] \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{Test for number 2.}
    \item[b] \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{Test for number 6.}
    \item[c] \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{Test for number 10.}
    \item[d] \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{Test for number 14.}
    \end{tablenotes}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

You can use option `online`, which change appearing of item's labels and write item's text as you wish:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=10, BCOR=8mm, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
%\caption{Test for the tnote in a threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tnote{a} \\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tnote{b} \\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tnote{c} \\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tnote{d} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]\scriptsize\raggedright % <---
    \item[a] Test for number 2.
    \item[b] Test for number 6.
    \item[c] Test for number 10.
    \item[d] Test for number 14.
    \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In your edit of the question you provide a suggestion for possible solution. If you change settings in it as follows. it works fine if item's label is shorter than 1.em (about three `\scriptsize` letters):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=10, BCOR=8mm, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}       % <---
\patchcmd\TPTdoTablenotes{%   <---
  \TPTnoteSettings
}{%
  \TPTnoteSettings
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{0.7em}% <---
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}% <---
  \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}% 
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\TPTdoTablenotes failed}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
%\caption{Test for the tnote in a threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tnote{a} \\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tnote{b} \\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tnote{c} \\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tnote{d} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\scriptsize\raggedright
    \item[a] Test for number 2.
    \item[bbb] Test for number 6.
    \item[c] Test for number 10.
    \item[d] Test for number 14.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **@Zarko**: thanks a lot for the help. The `parbox` is an interesting solution, but I was looking at something more fundamental, at the level of the note settings as I suggested above. Not sure if that's possible..............

Comment: @Euclides, it is possible with use option ˙online`, however style of notes is changed. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Euclides, see edited answer.

Comment: **@Zarko**: thanks a lot for the help once again. Need some time to process the information, before electing a solution..............

Comment: @Euclides, instead to saying "thanks" (at both answers) you can (according to policy of this site) upvote them (by clicking on up triangle at the top left side of answers) ;-)

Comment: **@Zarko**: I have my note labels always with one digit, so ``2em`` gives way too much space between label and note. For me a value of ``0.9em`` works fine. Also, in ``\begin{tablenotes}`` I didn't need to use the ``\raggedright`` option, only ``\flushleft``. Still, I would like to achieve a bit less separation between label and note.  The ``online`` option also has to much separation between label and note and is out of question, at least for me. I will compare the separations I get with ``parbox`` and with the aforementioned ``0.9em``..............

Comment: @Euclides, well, than you only need fine tuning of  `\labelwidth` and dropping out `\raggedright`  or instead it use `\RaggedRight` which is provided by `ragged2e` package (to my opinion it gives nicer formatting of items when table is narrow). I correct edit my answer accordingly, however, to me is the very promising to use a solution with use of `tabularray` as propose L.J.R in his answer.

Comment: **@Zarko**: I skipped [flushleft] and used ``\raggedright``, which allows me to use a smaller ``labelwidth`` of ``0.6em``, while keeping the alignment of multiline items. The result is quite similar to that of **@L.J.R.** below, with the advantage of having labels and notes with the same font and a solution for multipage tables. In addition, I seem to have more flexibility regarding vertical separation of items, which is helpful if you have multiline items. With my current knowledge, your latter **Edit:** solution is the best one for me and I will vote for it..............

Comment: **@Zarko**: I was happy with neither ``flushleft`` nor ``\raggedright``, as I think that all note labels should have a slight indentation. So, I tested more carefully the effects of  ``\setlength{\labelwidth}``, ``\setlength{\labelsep}``, etc.; and I think the most elegant solution for single digit (letter, symbol) labels referring to single or multiline notes is to use ``\setlength{\labelwidth}{1em}`` , ``\setlength{\labelsep}{-0.2em}``, and ``\setlength{\itemsep}{0.2em}``. This gives you freedom to chose the separation between label and note, while keeping latter indented/ justified.......

Comment: **@Zarko**: the latter is especially true, if one uses ``threeparttablex`` (in combination with ``longtable``, or course) whereby the table exhibits a ``\tiny`` font size. See [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527249/slight-misalignment-of-table-notes-when-using-tablenotes-in-combination-with-lon]..............

Answer (score 3):

I will give a solution for long tables with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Title},
  note{a} = {Test for number 2 number 2},
  note{b} = {Test for number 6 number 6},
  note{c} = {Test for number 10 number 10},
  note{d} = {Test for number 14 number 14},
]{colspec={XX},width=0.25\linewidth}
\toprule
  A & B \\
\midrule
   1234 &  2\TblrNote{a} \\
   3234 &  4             \\
   5234 &  6\TblrNote{b} \\
   7234 &  8             \\
   9234 & 10\TblrNote{c} \\
  11234 & 12             \\
  13234 & 14\TblrNote{d} \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I will add another example as requested by @Euclides:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=9cm,width=6cm,height=7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\SetTblrStyle{note-tag}{font=\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Title},
  note{a} = {Test for number 2 number 2 number 2},
  note{b} = {Test for number 6 number 6 number 6},
  note{c} = {Test for number 10 number 10 number 10},
  note{d} = {Test for number 14 number 14 number 14},
]{colspec={XX},width=0.8\linewidth,rowhead=1}
\toprule
  A & B \\
\midrule
   1234 &  2\TblrNote{a} \\
   3234 &  4             \\
   5234 &  6\TblrNote{b} \\
   7234 &  8             \\
   9234 & 10\TblrNote{c} \\
  11234 & 12             \\
  13234 & 14\TblrNote{d} \\
   1234 &  2\TblrNote{a} \\
   3234 &  4             \\
   5234 &  6\TblrNote{b} \\
   7234 &  8             \\
   9234 & 10\TblrNote{c} \\
  11234 & 12             \\
  13234 & 14\TblrNote{d} \\
   1234 &  2\TblrNote{a} \\
   3234 &  4             \\
   5234 &  6\TblrNote{b} \\
   7234 &  8             \\
   9234 & 10\TblrNote{c} \\
  11234 & 12             \\
  13234 & 14\TblrNote{d} \\
   1234 &  2\TblrNote{a} \\
   3234 &  4             \\
   5234 &  6\TblrNote{b} \\
   7234 &  8             \\
   9234 & 10\TblrNote{c} \\
  11234 & 12             \\
  13234 & 14\TblrNote{d} \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **@L.J.R.**: notes look nice. Can you build a multipage table using the same approach?

Comment: **@L.J.R.**: and also, is it possible to have the note labels with the same font as the notes themselves?

Comment: @Euclides I have edited my answer and added another example.

Comment: **@L.J.R.**: nice. Final question: is it possible to keep the same alignment of notes, but with all labels slightly indented? In other words, shift the whole "block of notes" slightly to the right without going beyond the right hand side of the ``\bottomrule``? Right now, all note labels start on the left hand side of the ``\bottomrule``. If this is possible, then, your solution is possibly a competing one..............

Comment: `\SetTblrStyle{note}{indent=1em,hang=1.7em}`.

Comment: **@L.J.R.**: nice. need some time to make a direct comparison with the result of ``threeparttablex`` in combination with ``longtable``..............

Comment: You use this package often ahahah :-) +1

Comment: @Sebastiano In fact, I am the author of this package. :)

Comment: @L.J.R. noooooooooo :-(  what a bad figure I have made :-(((((((((

Answer (score 2):

For information, here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\tabularnote`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}
\NiceMatrixOptions{notes/code-before=\scriptsize}
\centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tabularnote{Test for number 2.}\\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tabularnote{Test for number 6.}\\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tabularnote{Test for number 10.}\\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tabularnote{Test for number 14.}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: **@F.Pantigny**: thanks a lot for the help. Need some time to process the information, before electing a solution..............

Comment: **@F.Pantigny**: is is possible to combine your solution with ``longtable``?

Comment: @Euclides: Unfortunately, no (maybe in a future version)